# Unable to debug xamarin.forms application. When I am running it only deploys app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

2 days ago, I was able to debug my xamarin.forms application on Android Devices (Pixel 2 XL, API 29) and Emulators (API 27 & 28). But after installing few Nuget Packages, it only deploys on the device/emulator but not could not debug the app.

I tried changing the configuration of the visual studio to Deploy and Debug and still it only deploys on the device instead starting it in debug mode

Comment: I Uninstalled the nuget packages and still it doesnt starts in debug mode instead deploys on the device.

Comment: Post your Android Options and Build for possible misconfiguration.

Comment: Probably, you have tried this already but to be on the safe side. Uninstall the app, delete all bin and obj folders in your solution, restart your device & computer and give it another shot. Sometimes the debugging session fails because one of the ports it uses is still blocked by a previous session

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unchecked the option of `Use shared Runtime` in Android Options.

[image]